# lvm and hardware raid: hardware raid 5 and raid 1 in single volume group?

Tags: raid, hardware, lvm

I have a system with pre configured hardware RAID. It has 2 disks in a RAID1 configuration. It has a further 6 disks in a RAID5 configuration. The 6 disk RAID5 is split (by the hardware) to look like 2 separate disks:

```
/dev/sda - RAID1 2x discs
/dev/sdb - RAID5 6x discs (half of each disk)
/dev/sdc - RAID5 6x discs (half of each disk)
```

I have an lvm physical volume for each of the above. I am considering adding PV /dev/sda and PV /dev/sdb, and possibly /dev/sdc to the same volume group.

To my naive view of LVM/RAID, this is looks like logical volumes would be backed by a mixture of RAID5 and RAID1. What are the risks, ineffciencies or management difficulties with this approach ?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: What type of RAID controller is this?

Comment: I have it listed as "LSI9260-8i" http://www.lsi.com/products/raid-controllers/pages/megaraid-sas-9260-8i.aspx

Comment: Also, I meant 6 disks in RAID 5 not 4 ! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any ability to change the hardware RAID configuration?

Comment: Not in this instance. But for subsequent projects possibly.

Comment: You need to understand how the second RAID5 virtual drive is configured in order to proceed.

Comment: OK, can I re-ask but with tighter bounds:

Comment: Well, it just makes sense to know how the disks are laid-out. I don't know that I'd combine the virtual disks (hardware) into a single volume group without knowing the full composition of the virtual disks.

Comment: 1. Could this "combined" configuration remove the redundancy & recovery benefits to data stored on either RAID virtual drive ?  
2. Is the io performance of this "combined" configuration any worse than the slowest of the current RAID virtual drives ?  
3. Does this combined "configuration" affect which physical drives can safely be hot swapped ?

Comment: (Sorry cant move to chat) Oh, i see. I think. From the perspective of the raid configuration bios: Discs are listed as "slots". The first two discs are mapped to "drive group definition" (DG) 1. This first DG is assigned to a single RAID1 span. The remaining six discs are mapped to a second DG. The first "half" of the second DG is mapped to one span, and the second half is mapped to a final span. Thus, in the terminology of the RAID bios we get 3 spans. Span 1 is RAID 1 and corresponds to /dev/sda, Spans 2 & 4 are RAID 5 and map to sdb and sdc respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest doing this, especially combining virtual disks (hardware) into a single volume group under LVM without knowing the exact composition of the virtual disks. This will have implications with:

- Redundancy - What would be the impact of a failed disk be? E.g. a failure of disk #5 will compromise DG's 2 and 3.
- Performance - Performance on a 2-disk mirror will have a different profile than a 6-disk RAID5. You won't have any control over where your data is.
- Supportability - It sounds like a messed-up configuration. I wouldn't want to inherit it. If you have an option to change things, you should.